# How could I capture the final url after redirects are followed with python, django, or shell based tool?

Tags: python, django, linux

Ok I'm doing a Django project where I have affiliate links for different sites. So I want to be able to automatically determine where the final domain ends up being after all the redirects are followed because allot of the affiliate links will be from a 3rd party rather than the destination it's self. For example an affiliate link may look like this:

```
   http://afl.affiliatenetworking.com/tracker.asp?ref=abc123afialiate
```

but may end up redirecting to amazon.com for example. 
Is there anything in python (or an external utility on linux) that can let me know where I end up after all the redirects are followed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By default, `urllib2.urlopen()` follows redirects. The response has a `geturl()` method which returns the address of the actual place you ended up. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html).

Comment: Hmm, thanks for that, It might work on pages that send redirect headers, but it didn't appear to work on the affiliate page I tried. looking at the source grabbed with wget I see that they use a meta http-equiv="refresh" tag. Any way to get that to work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any custom tools to perform such a check. Basic shell utils are enough:

```
curl -s --head --location 'http://afl.affiliatenetworking.com/tracker.asp?ref=abc123afialiate'|grep '^Location'|tail -n 1
```

The above will follow all of the redirects and extract the last `Location` header, which is the final destination.

Comment: I got no output from this command. Probably do to the same thing I said in the comment on the other answer.

Comment: Surely. To be honest, using meta tag to redirect is so lame I can hardly express it. Anyway, in this situation you need to parse the output HTML to access that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try FancyURLopener ( http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.FancyURLopener), it handles most of the redirect cases, and as it subclasses urlopener, you can use geturl(). So, you can simply say:

```
fancy = urllib.FancyURLopener({})
link = fancy.open('http://some/affiliate/link')
final_link = link.geturl()
```

Works great for me :)